# How can I understand the (no) independence property in this very simple setting of first order logic?

Tags: first-order-logic, model-theory, machine-learning

My understanding of logic is limited to first order logic without functions with finite set of domain constants, and with herbrand semantics. Now in this setting, I would like to understand the independence property of logical theories --- My goal is to understand VC dimension in this setting.

So let us say I have a FOL language with only the predicate $R$, and domain constants $n$, represented by $[n] = \{1,...,n\}$. Does this language have the independence property?

In my understanding of independence property thus far, this language will have the independence property, if we can write a formula for picking out any subset of the directed graphs on $[n]$. Is this correct?

Furthermore, if I do not put any restrictions, then I can always axiomatize any graph on $n$ in this language, by simply writing out the graph edges in this language.

However, if I restrict that I only allow formulas with no constants, then I do not have independence property, as I can not distinguish between isomorphic graphs. Is this correct?

Finally, How can I compute the VC dimension of a theory/formula?

I am sorry if my question is all over the place, but I am finding it hard to get a rigorous understanding of independence property in herbrand logic.

Comment: It's natural that you're having difficulty getting a rigorous understanding of the independence property in Herbrand logic over a finite domain, because the independence property is studied in the context of ordinary first-order logic, with the usual semantics (not Herbrand semantics!), over infinite structures. Do you have a reference for a situation in which people study a variant of the independence property in herbrand logic?

Comment: My motivation is driven by these types of works on the cross-roads of logic and Machine learning: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.05487.pdf (see lemma 5.4) ; https://www.lics.rwth-aachen.de/global/show_document.asp?id=aaaaaaaaabbtbym